# Changing a Kentico site display name disassociates the default stylesheet

Tags: kentico

I created a dev instance of my Kentico sites from a copy of my staging instance. I changed all the site display names in the Sites admin module to denote that these were now all the dev sites instead of staging ones and it broke all my sites by setting the SiteDefaultStyleheetID and SiteDefaultEditorStylesheet columns to NULL on the CMS_Site table for each renamed site.

To be clear, I did *not* mess with any site code names when I did this. They all stayed the same. I also created this dev instance by copying the entire file system (7-zipped) and db (created a .bak file) from the staging server to a dev server. I didn't do any export or importing of sites to create this dev instance.

What's more, the "Site CSS stylesheet:" and "Editor CSS stylesheet:" dropdown menus don't display any of the stylesheets assigned to the renamed sites. However, when I check to see if any stylesheets are assigned to those sites under "Assigned Objects", all the appropriate stylesheets show up as assigned to their proper site.

If I brute force the default stylesheet IDs back onto the Site records in SQL, the sites will display properly, but the "Site CSS stylesheet:" and "Editor CSS stylesheet:" dropdown menus ins Sites will remain empty. Also, If I edit the site display names again, the default stylesheet columns get reset to NULL.

Does anyone know if this is intended behavior? Has anyone encountered this before, and if so, how did you remedy the problem?

It looks suspiciously like a bug for such an important part of a site such as a default stylesheet to break simply because the site's display name changed while the integer ID, GUID, and code name all remained the same.

Comment: Oh, yeah. That might help ;D

Comment: Questions added!

Comment: This issue seems to meet the threshold for calling in the cavalry. I've got an open ticket with Kentico support. Their friendly support engineer can't replicate the issue in a fresh instance of Kentico 12. Our instance began life back in version 6 or 7 and was recently upgraded from 8.2 to 12, so it stands to reason this is upgrade related. Stay tuned.

Comment: The site name change is probably the red herring here. I was able to reproduce the issue only if I broke the macro signatures by changing the hash salt string. 
Have you changed the connection string or the hash string salt for macros? Are there any other errors in the Event log? 
I would try re-signing macros - https://docs.kentico.com/k12/macro-expressions/troubleshooting-macros/working-with-macro-signatures#Workingwithmacrosignatures-Re-signingmacros

Comment: Right you are, it was the macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I didn't resign all the Kentico macros after performing the update. As I don't use them in my daily development, and this was just a test, it never occurred to me to do that. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

If you [look at the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/deploying-websites/exporting-and-importing-sites/export-folder-structure) you'll see the setup with files and folders specific to CSS and Themes.  They are specific to the sites code name.  If you change it, this will break the URL path Kentico looks for automatically.  If you want to define the site for each environment, I'd suggest simply updating the display name and not the code name.  Honestly, there's no reason to change the code name, except to make more work for yourself.

Comment: That's just it though, I didn't alter the code name and everything still broke!

Comment: Then how did you copy the site back from staging to dev?  The best bet is to simply take a backup of the DB and code base and make your modifications from there.  If you exported and imported, your ID's will be different and cause problems.

Comment: Just updated the question to reflect your comment, I did just that to create this dev instance. It's a mirror image of the staging instance, down to the integer-based IDs on all records.